# How can I use a function to run another function?

Tags: javascript

I'm sorry if this is a horrible question, I'm a beginner to JS.
So what I'm trying to do is have a function that runs right away and then that function will run other functions if a certain thing is true.
But, when I run it, it says that the function is not yet defined and I can't figure out how to solve this problem. I thank you for your time.

```
function start() {
var start = prompt('Yes or no?');
if (start === 'Yes') {
yes();
}
```

but because its in the beginning the functions it runs are below it and are not able to run.

Comment: Include the code that you have tried. You post without the code doesnt help

Comment: You might be using runtime functions which aren't hoisted and thus the issue, if you use normal function declaration, it shouldn't raise any errors whatsoever.

Comment: How do you trigger this function?

Comment: I use start(); on a line above it, but i need it to be a function so I can use it again later

Comment: in js all the functions in a scope is hoisted so it doesn't matter if function to be called is declared below or above in write context.

Answer (score 1):

```js
//declare a function called yes
var yes = function(){
  alert('You said yes');
};

function start() {
    
      var start = prompt('Yes or no?');
      if (start === 'Yes') {
       yes();
      }
  }

start(); //call first function
```

Passing function as a parameter example.

```js
var fun1 = function(callback) {
  var res = prompt('Your ans please');
  callback(res);//pass response to function.
};

var handleRes = function(res){
  if (res==='yes'){
    alert('you said yes');
  }
  else if(res==='no'){
    alert('you said no');
  }
  else {
    alert('you did not say yes or no');
  }
};

//call fun1 pass handleRes function to it for callback
fun1(handleRes);
```

Comment: How would i go from the yes function back to the start function? Is that possible?

Comment: yes it is possible.. you can call that function again in yes() .. something like.

var yes = function(){ alert ('you said yes'); start();}

Comment: but this would be a bad example.. what you should do is use call backs and pass the function as a parameter. I will post an example for you.

Comment: edits aside, i'm not sure the callback really makes sense because `prompt` is a synchronous function – there's just no need to abstract the control flow with a continuation. I think this only serves to distract a learner at this skill level.

Answer (score -1):

Order in which you write your function matters in JavaScript in some scenarios. Probably the function you are calling is written below it.

Comment: I tried to put the other function above the one that I'm calling it from. But, i'm trying to call function A from Function B and Function B from Function A. How could I format this code?

Comment: If functionA is called first then define functionB first. Then functionA and then call functionA. Refer answer by Ravi S. Singh.